# JavaFX without extending Application class

Tags: java, oop, javafx, extends

When we create a javafx application, we usually extends the Application class.

```
public class Myjavafx extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("click me");

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("my app");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

but can i do it without extending the Application class?
i have tried to create javafx application without extending it.

```
public class Myjavafx{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application myapp = new Application(){
            @Override
            public void start(Stage primaryStage){
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.setText("click me");

                BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
                pane.setCenter(btn);

                Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,250);

                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.setTitle("my app");
                primaryStage.show();
            }
        };
        myapp.launch(args);
    }
}
```

but it turn out an error

```
class Myjavafxis not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
```

is it necessary to extends Application class?or am i doing it wrong.

Comment: Where do you declare `myapp`?

Comment: See new answer.

Comment: `Application.launch()` creates a new instance of the application class by reflection. An anonymous class is used to create a single, one-time, instance of a class without naming the class. Since you would subsequently need `Application.launch()` to create another instance of the class, using an anonymous class is simply not the correct way to do this. You can create a named inner class (must be public) as in the linked question, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are already extending `Application` by creating an anonymous inner class. However, JavaFX requires that you extend `Application` from a named class. This is because `launch()` is a `static` method which creates the `Application` instance by reflection. The way you call `launch()` here hides this fact. It would be better to call `Application.launch()` rather than `myapp.launch()` since this makes it clear the `launch()` is `static`.

Comment: The OP is already extending `Application`, though.

Comment: @James_D Technically, yes, the anonymous inner class extends `Application`. However, it appears that the named class must extend `Application`.

Comment: The problem is that (unless you use the convenience version of the method) `Application.launch()` requires you to provide the application class, which is impossible to do if you make that class anonymous.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the clarification. I edited my answer with some more details.

Comment: @James_D You can still get the `Class` object of an anonymous class with `myapp.getClass()`. However, JavaFX requires a no-args constructor which the anonymous class does not have.

Comment: True. I think the constructor probably exists but is just not accessible. E.g. `Class.getConstructor()` will only return a *public* no-arg constructor. (Of course, once you are instantiating something merely to provide access to the class that defines it, you are clearly well into "this is not the intended approach" territory.)

Comment: @James_D More accurately, my attempt with `Application.launch(myapp.getClass(), args);` throws a `NoSuchMethodException`. I am unsure if this exception means that the constructor does not exist or that it is just inaccessible.

Comment: If you check the stack trace, it's calling `getConstructor()`, which explicitly will only check for public constructors. If you do, e.g. `myapp.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor()` you'll see that the constructor exists. (`isAccessible()` returns false on that constructor). Kind of redundant at this point.